# Is "pick me up some dinner" correct?

Tags: pronouns

Is "pick me up some dinner" correct? It sounds alright, and I said it in conversation, but I can't help but wonder whether it's wrong now.

Comment: I would characterize it as [_dialectal_](https://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/dialect), not "wrong."

Comment: What is it that you think is wrong with it?

Comment: It looks OK to me. I'd read "me" as an indirect object of "pick up", equivalent to "for me" in the rearranged sentence "pick up some dinner for me."

Comment: @tchrist It just sounded weird. There's no other real way for me to explains it. See how that sentence was wrong? Some people know the error is wrong because they actually understand grammar, but others (me) can feel out an error. Often this freak sense fails.

Comment: https://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/prescriptivism-and-descriptivism/ James, join us on the descriptivist dark-side.  Your sentence was perfectly fine, and matches common usage in my part of the world.  Anyone who judges you for speaking plainly is a prescriptivist and rude to boot.

Comment: @jamesfdearborn Well it is idiomatic (in that one cannot infer the meaning from the normal senses of the words). But it is an everyday expression throughout most of the anglosphere.

Comment: When I was in grade school, a portion of English grammar, as taught to native speakers, consisted of examples of common mistakes and the "correct" form. The sentence in the question is very similar to an example taught of such a mistake. It was selected for a lesson because it was relatively common informal usage. It still is. "Real" English is as people do.  Grade school teachers wouldn't get very far in teaching the preferred grammar if they portrayed the "mistakes" as common and acceptable.  But common = actual English.  You just wouldn't see that construction in formal writing or speaking.

Answer (score 1):

"me" in this example is an indirect object, it means "for me" or "to me".

> "Pick up for me a burger on the way back."

"Pick up" is a phrasal verb. With phrasal verbs you can often(not always) insert the object between the two words forming the phrasal verb:

> "Look me up in the phone book."
>  "Put me down! Get your hands off me."
>   "Work it out for yourself."

Here the phrasal verbs are "look up", "put down" and "work out".

The second word in the last examples are direct objects. The following are examples of indirect objects inserted within the phrasal verbs with a direct object of the verb following:

> "Bring me up some coffee."
>  "Cut me off a piece of cake."
>  "Get me back
>   my licence."
>  "Send me back that letter I wrote." 
> "Set me up a meeting with him." 
> And of course "Pick me up some dinner."

The indirect objects (me) in these examples correspond to "for me" or "to me".

I've gone through a list of these phrasal verbs, and it turns out only a few of them work out with an indirect object embedded in the phrasal verb followed by a direct object. The ones I've listed I found acceptable. But let's try with some others:

> "Switch me on that light." (Sounds strange)
>  "Hang me up that phone." (Hang up
>   that phone for me; sounds really wrong.) 
> "Find me out whether he's
>   serious." (sounds really wrong).

I can't detect a pattern here.

The earlier examples I gave I find acceptable, at least informally.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hair unusual, but it's correct. It's just "pick up", meaning to buy or acquire, and using two objects: "me", the indirect object the action was done for; and "some dinner", the direct object being picked up.

Although it might sound a bit awkward, probably because of the two objects, it's definitely correct, and I'd probably say the same thing. Alternatively, it might be the "some dinner" that sounds strange to you, meaning "some food for dinner", but that's also common in of itself.

Comment: It would most commonly be used with a family member or some such where Fred says to Sally, "While you're at the grocery, pick me up some orange juice," or some such.